# Machine Learning Algorithm for ranking based one data-set based on another data set

Tags: machine-learning

Can you please suggest me machine learning algorithm for below requirement.

I have a data-set with 8-10 fields (Typically it hold only one record at a time) for which I need to compare against other data-set which will have multiple matching records.

I need to rank records in 2nd data-set which matches with 1st data-set.

As per knowledge, K-Nearest neighbors is seems useful to achieve this functionality.

I feel KNN doesn't need explicit training for this requirement. 
Please suggest & recommend if another useful approaches & algorithms.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO; please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use Artificial neural networks , which are termed as **universal function approximaters**. You can train it on the record in the 1st dataset. Then make predictions on the records present in the second dataset. The record which gets the highest probability,  ranks the first. You can know more from [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/applied-deep-learning-part-1-artificial-neural-networks-d7834f67a4f6).